# Is $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^4}&(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I want to check

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^4}&(x,y)\ne(0,0)\\0&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

for continuity.

I think the function is continuous at the origin.

If we put $y=kx^2, k\in \Bbb R$
then $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^4} \text{becomes}$$
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2\cdot |kx^2|}{x^2+(kx^2)^4}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|kx^4|}{x^2+k^4x^8} \ \text{with} \ x\ne 0$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|kx^2|}{1+k^4x^6}$$
$$=\frac{0}{1} = 0$$

Is this right or wrong?

And is there a $c$, such that $g(x,y) = f(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $g(0,0) = c$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is continuous in origin.

But you didn't demonstrate that the limit is equal to zero. Restricting it to just $y=kx^2$ is just one way you can approach the origin, you cannot say that the limit exists. The only conclusion from your result is that if the limit exists it must be $0$.

To demonstrate it formally you can use the Squeeze theorem as follows:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\bigg|\frac{x^2\cdot |y|}{x^2+y^4}\bigg| \le \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\bigg|\frac{x^2\cdot |y|}{x^2}\bigg|
$$
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{{x^2}\cdot |y|}{x^2}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}|y|=0
$$

We formally demonstrated that limit equals to $0$ when $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$. As it is equal to the value of the function by definition of the function we can say that it is continuous.

Comment: Since $x^2$ occurs in the denominator in your calculation, it seems worthwhile to add that the calculation is needed only for $x\neq0$, because when $x=0$ (but $y\neq0$), the original expression vanishes.